# Python: how to import a class which was compiled in an exe?

Tags: python, compilation, executable

Previously, I compiled a first.py file into first.exe; there is only a class in the "first.py":

```
class auth():
    def __init__(self,a):
        self.a=a
```

Now I'm working with a new py file. I want to import the auth() class through the executable "first.exe". Is there any idea to do this?

Comment: It should be in a DLL, not an exe.

Comment: how do you compiled it?

Comment: @Scantlight I used py2exe

Comment: In that case it is an encapsulated executable, you cannot use modules within it from another process.  If there is only a class in it, why did you compile it as an exe?

Comment: @cdarke Because I want to encrypt a small part of my main program with a USB key. However, the USB key is used to encypt an entire single exe. So I planned to encrypt an outer exe (that is first.exe in this case), and try to call it in the main program to decide whether or not to reveal the hidden function.

Comment: You can only call it as a child process, using something like `subprocess` in the standard library.  If you want to run the code in the same process then it has to be a DLL.